# Internationalization of Vuetify data table header

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3, vue-i18n

I'm trying to internationalize my data table header using Vuetify + I18n.

When I translate my normal code, it works correctly, but now I need to translate the header of my data table built with Vuetify.

I've already tried to add the code `this.$vuetify.t('$vuetify.activity.username')` or `this.$t('$vuetify.activity.username')` in the header, but nothing happens. The language stays English (en) always.

Does someone know how to fix it?

I send below my code.

Thank you in advance.

**Activity.vue**

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: 'ID', value: 'id', width: '1%', align: 'left' },
        { text: this.$vuetify.t('$vuetify.activity.username'), value: 'username', width: '1%' },
        ...
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

**main.js**

```js
import messages from './assets/lang'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  messages
})

// Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  lang: {
    t: (key, ...params) => i18n.t(key, params)
  }
})
```

**./assets/lang/index.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  en: {
    ...
    $vuetify: {
      dataIterator: {
        rowsPerPageText: 'Items per page:',
        ...
      },
      ...
      activity: {
        username: 'Username'
      }
    }
  },
  pt: {
    ...
    $vuetify: {
      dataIterator: {
        rowsPerPageText: 'Itens por página:',
        ...
      },
      ...
      activity: {
        username: 'Nome do usuário'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your main.js locale you have mentioned as 'en'. Is it translating to 'pt' if you set locale as 'pt' ?

Comment: Yes, all code is translating to 'pt' when I set locale as 'pt'. Just the data table header that is not translating, unfortunately.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For Vuetify 2.x

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" ...
```

And put into the computed data

```
 computed: {   
    headers () {
      return [
        {
          text: this.$t('title'),
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'title'
        },
```

For Vuetify 1.x

you can put your translation function into headerCell slot. It won't work when you put the function in the `headers:` object in Activity.vue, just put there your translation keys and use the template with slot.

```
<v-data-table>
    ....
    <template slot="headerCell" slot-scope="props">
        {{ $t(props.header.text) }}
    </template>
    ....
```

Comment: I'm sorry for answering so late. Your example worked very well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

You can put your header in a computed function. When the local changes, the headers will be updated

```
computed:{

    headers(){
      return [
        { text: 'ID', value: 'id', width: '1%', align: 'left' },
        { text: this.$vuetify.t('$vuetify.activity.username'), value: 'username', width: '1%' },
        ...
      ]
    }
...
}
```